# Managing access from a Console App to a Web API on Azure

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular application deployed on Azure secured with Azure Active Directory. To achieve that, I have followed this guide : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular.

So, in order to query the website's Web API, the user needs to be authenticated on Azure Active Directory. So far, everything works great.

Now, we have a internal service, not deployed on Azure, that needs to query a method of that Web API, which is already secured as previously mentioned.

Is there a way, without using the Api Management service, to give access to the internal service in order to call the secured Web API without having the need to use a AAD username / password?

I tried using ADAL librairy, but all the example that I have seen prompt an AAD username password login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the web API which protected by Azure AD without interaction to provide username and password, we can use the **Client Credentials** flow( refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service#request-an-access-token)).

And there is the code to use the azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet for your reference:

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
string clientId = "";
string secret = "";
string resource = "";

var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential).Result.AccessToken;

Console.WriteLine(token);
```

Comment: Yes, there it is. I didn't know where to put the secret key on Azure in order to make the call. Thanks!